# What makes Bind consider itself authoritative for a zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

As I understand, dig sets the "aa" flag in case the reply has `Authoritative Answer` flag in DNS message header with a value of 1. When does Bind set this `Authoritative Answer` flag to 1? When `named.conf` has the zone statement for that zone? As much as I tested, it has nothing to do with NS records in the zone.

Comment: Your last point is related to the fact that you can have setup where you have an "hidden" master nameserver for your zone that feeds other nameserver that are themselves as NS record in the zone to be queried by clients, where the master nameserver remains hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When does Bind set this Authoritative Answer flag to 1? When named.conf has the zone statement for that zone? As much as I tested, it has nothing to do with NS records in the zone.

You are correct, BIND considers itself authoritative for a zone whenever it is configured as master or slave.

- In practice this is fine, as the server will never get consulted for authoritative lookups unless traffic is directed to it by recursive servers. Typically this happens by following referrals from other DNS servers.
- Exceptions: Forwarders configured on recursive servers, or local authoritative zones that override recursion. (server considers itself authoritative, no need to recurse)

The one case where the `NS` records do have an influence on authority is when you have `NS` records other than the mandatory ones at the top of the zone file. This declares a delegation to other DNS servers, and defines the boundary of a [zone cut](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-6). The server will no longer return `aa=1` for that name or any names falling beneath it. Instead, it will only return a referral to the nameservers indicated by the `NS` record, optionally including glue records in the Additional section.